# Optimize perf / profile Hg Workbench

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, workbench

My Hg Workbench is sometimes very slow.
I am under windows7, using last version of Tortoise Hg.
I have several large repositories being tracked by Hg locally
For example, I have one repository that

- has been converted from CVS using cvs2hg (from svn2hg)
- has more than 7000 changesets
- is more than 1GB heavy
- uses extensions largefiles, hgk, mercurial_keyring
- has several binary files being tracked as large files
- has a few binary files not tracked as large files( including one file of 300 MB)

With this repo, it can take

- from 10 seconds, up to 30 seconds to open the repository
- from 3 seconds, up to 10 seconds to change a changeset

and sometimes, doing a filter in the changeset list can last several minutes.

Note 1 : This is the case for all the team (approx 10 people) using this repository, not only on my PC

Note 2 : in the past, it was even much much longer but that was due to the collumn "Changes" being displayed. Now, it is not as bad but far from good anyway.

Note 3 : this repos has been cloned from a RhodeCode server but the problem is in local 
configuration, not during push or pull operation, so I think it is not related.

Note 4 : after cvs2hg conversion, I had a problem of End Of Line (I had been unable to make EOL conversion to work correctly with the convertor, I don't know why). So after the conversion, I had to apply a EOL conversion on all my text files, to commit and to push. That made quite a big changeset. I don't think that is the reason for my problem because as far as I remember, it was already slow before this conversion, but I prefered to notice it anyway.

Would anybody have any idea about what's wrong with my config ?
Is there a way I could have a profile log or even a general log that could give me information about what is taking so long ?

Thanks in advance

Antoine